# 960gs grid Inside grid

Tags: layout, 960.gs, grid-system

Is it possible to have the inside grid surrounded where the outer grid contents flows around the inside grid as what happens in an image float left/right.

```
---------------------------|
|                          |
|  grid_8                  |
|                          |
|------------|             |
|            |             |
| grid_4     |             |         
|            |             |
|------------|             |
|                          |
|                          |
|--------------------------|
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you asking?  Is this related to technologies such as HTML or CSS?  You should add tags so that your post shows up for people who follow relevant technologies.  The tag `grid` doesn't help at all.

Comment: Oh, This is related to using the 960 grid system nested grids. Is it possible to create a subgrid as in the diagram. I can do that HTML but was wondering how to do it using the grid system. I hope I have explained better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/qCJEF/2/

CSS

```
.grid_8{
    width:960px;
    background-color:red;
    border:#FFF 1px dashed;
    padding:95px 0 110px;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
.grid_4{
    width:480px;
    background-color:blue;
    border:#FFF dashed 1px;
    padding:100px 0;
    margin:100px 0 0 0;
}
```